# zsh tilde (~) expands differently on OS X

Tags: git, ssh, zsh

Not sure what causes this...

system: OSX 10.9.2
shell: zsh with oh-my-zsh in tmux

```
> echo $HOME
/Users/xxmplus
> echo ~
/Users/xxmplus
> echo ~xxmplus
/home/xxmplus
```

This is annoying because my ssh does not work properly...

```
> ssh -T xxmplus@github.com
Could not create directory '/home/xxmplus/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/xxmplus/.ssh/known_hosts).
Hi xxmplus! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The most probable cause is that the home directory defined in the user database is different to what being set as `$HOME` by your profile and login scripts.**

As for,

```
> echo $HOME
/Users/xxmplus
> echo ~
/Users/xxmplus
```

The above is strictly according to spec, a standalone `~` is simply defined to be $HOME in POSIX, so this proves little.

But this is different:

```
> echo ~xxmplus
/home/xxmplus
```

The spec says the following,

> ... the tilde-prefix shall be replaced by a pathname of the initial working directory associated with the login name obtained using the getpwnam() ... If the system does not recognize the login name, the results are undefined

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01

So another quite unlikely option is that you’ve run into the undefined behaviour part of the spec – this can be the case when the login name (xxmplus) is not recognised on the box, specifically, it cannot be obtained with [getpwnam()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwnam.html), however the simpler explanation is that it is there and you have to simply change the home directory in the user database.

Comment: I think you are right. I asked my admin to reset my account and it works fine now. Thanks!